# Facebook API returning blank list for get_connections

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve my entire friend list using Python for Facebook. Here's my code.

```
import facebook
import json

def pretty_print(obj): 
    print json.dumps(obj, indent=4)

access_token = "my_token"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)

pretty_print(graph.get_object('me'))
print
pretty_print(graph.get_connections('me', 'friends'))
```

get_object('me') runs fine and returns a json object containing my account details, whereas get_connections() returns a blank list -

```
{
    "data": []
}
```

My access token has the read_friendlists permission.

Comment: /me/friends only return friends that have granted user_friends to your app